# Outlook 2016 Items count vs Unread count mismatch

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, shared-mailbox

In Outlook 2016 (running on Office 365 mail), If I highlight the "inbox" folder, the 'Items' count shows 95 but the 'Unread' count shows 91.  If I log into the OWA, the Inbox matches with the 91. I don't know what the 4 items are.

Also, I am unable to mark all as read and see what remains due to this being a shared mailbox.

Comment: Try toggling [offline mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-from-working-offline-to-online-2460e4a8-16c7-47fc-b204-b1549275aac9)

Comment: Tried running in online only mode and then re enabling cache mode, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Just close Outlook and delete the OST file that is associated with mailbox. Start Outlook, it will synchronize the mailbox again and you shouldn't see these "extra" items anymore.

Comment: I tried the steps you suggested, however no change.  I also built the same user profile on a totally different workstation and the same error was happening.